# Confused with my Gauss-Jordan Elimination code

Tags: java, algorithm

So, I've been working on this java algorithm from this pseudo-code on Rosetta code, and I think it's really close to working it's just the last column of the values is wrong.  I was wondering if anyone could take a peek and show me my error.  I've tried to search but I just cant figure it out. Thanks.

```
public static double[][] gaussJordan2(double[][] gauss)
{
    int lead = 0;
    int rowCount = gauss.length;
    int columnCount = gauss[0].length;

    for(int r = 0; r < gauss.length; r++)
    {
        if(columnCount <= lead)
        {
            //return gauss;
        }

        int i = r;

        while(gauss[i][lead] == 0)
        {
            i++;

            if(rowCount == i)
            {
                i = r;
                lead++;

                if(columnCount == lead)
                {
                    //return gauss;
                }
            }
        }

        swapRows(gauss, i, r);

        if(gauss[r][lead] != 0)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < gauss[r].length; j++)
            {
                gauss[r][j] /= gauss[r][lead];
            }
        }

        for(i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
        {
            if (i != r)
            {
                double f = gauss[i][lead];

                for (int k = 0; k < gauss[r].length; k++)
                {
                    gauss[i][k] -= f * gauss[r][k];
                    printMatrix(gauss);
                }
            }
        }
        lead++;
    }

    printMatrix(gauss);
    return gauss;
}
```

//HERE IS MY SWAP ROWS CODE:

public static double[][] swapRows(double[][] a, int highRow, int lowRow) {

```
            double grab = 0.0;
            double place = 0.0;

            for (int i = highRow; i < a.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < a[0].length; j++) {
                            grab = a[highRow][j];
                            place = a[lowRow][j];
                            a[highRow][j] = place;
                            a[lowRow][j] = grab;
                    }
            }
            printMatrix(a);
            return a;

    }
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample input and the expected and actual output?

Comment: You should try to write some unit tests. Look up JUnit.

Comment: Oops: so here is my Array I'm passing to it: double [][] a = { {1, 2, -1, -4 }, {2, 3, -1, -11}, {-2, 0, -3, 22}};  I'm expecthing this to output: {{1   0   0   -8},
{0   1   0   1},
{0   0   1   -2}} but I get this: {{1.0  0.0 0.0 80.0}, 
{0.0 1.0 0.0 -29.0}, 
{-0.0 -0.0 1.0 26.0}}

Comment: The problem is solved, or still unsolved ?

Comment: How does `swapRows` look?

Comment: added swap rows up there

Comment: You can have a look into my simple implementation: http://pastebin.com/ff4UUkPR Please note that comparing to zero like this: `a==0` is a terrible idea, since `double` has only limited precision, use `Math.abs(a) < epsilon` for suitably chosen epsilon (also note that i can affort to compare to zero since i use `BigRational` class which have unlimited* precision)